# "Unblock me" puzzle representation

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am trying to implement a program that solves the "Unblock me" puzzle. For those who dont know it, "Unblock me" is a sliding block puzzle where you have a board with 1x1, 1x2, 2x1 and 2x2 boxes and the goal is to move the red box out of the board through an opening.

My question is how can i represent a board state? I searched throught the internet and found a suggestion to represent the state like this.

For example this board: [Board State](http://prntscr.com/52ymia)

Representation: [Grid representation](http://prntscr.com/52yn9w)

I can understand how this representation works. The problem comes when i want to move one of the boxes. How can i check if a box is 1x1, 1x2, 2x1 or 2x2 in order to check if the wanted move is possible or not??

Any ideas on how i could do that, or any other "easier" representations?

Answer (score 3):

I would do:

- Width of grid
- Height of grid
- List of boxes, and for each box:

  - Dimensions of the box (doesn't have to be a square or rectangle)

    - Width of the box
    - Height of the box
    - Each of the cells that are occupied within the bounds of the box
  - Position of top-left cell, so coordinates (x, y)
  - Name of the box (e.g., "A", "B", "C")

If this is an unblock puzzle where you need to slide a box outside the grid, you'll also need:

- Coordinates of the grid cell that has the exit
- The position of the exit for that cell (e.g., "north", "east", etc). This is necessary when the exit is located in a corner cell.

This should allow you to perform any computations as necessary. Given the top-left cell of where a box is located, the dimensions of the box and knowing what cells are occupied within the box, you can compute whether a collision is taking place or not.

The above representation also supports arbitrary shapes, not just rectangles and squares.

Comment: Well i have only Squares and Rectangles. Anyway, assuming i have the top-left cell coordinates, how do i check if it is 1x1, 1x2, 2x1 or 2x2? Sounds like a HUGE "if" statement.

Comment: Oh now i saw you edited, i thing i get that.

Comment: Unblock me is a 5x5 grid. Assuming that the screen is 400x400px, i would say each unit is 80px. So a 1x2 block listed horizontally at the top left would be (160,80). Maybe do a detection on (159,79) to see if object exist?

Comment: @FortMauris: detection should take place on abstract coordinates, so in the 5x5 grid. It shouldn't take place using screen pixel coordinates as that can change later for arbitrary reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You could always have an array of the same dimensions as the "grid", the exit would have a special value of -1, empty squares have 0 and each block would have the number of the block.

You could then have a Check function that takes a block number and a direction and for each current cell that has the block number as the value check that the adjacent cell either has the same block number or is <1.

The move function would shift the values in the required direction setting zero, with a little care on the order things are done you can just start with the first set the cell in the required direction to the required number and the current square to 0.  Minimal ifs and a couple of loops.